# Installing the Eigen library in Visual C++ 2010

Tags: c++, eigen

How can I install the Eigen library in Visual C++ 2010?  I downloaded the library from [eigen.tuxfamily](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org)

But I do not know how can install it on my Visual C++.  I want to run a program I downloaded and it has the following:

```
#include <Eigen/Core>
using namespace Eigen;
```

How can I do this?  I have tried to look online but I seem to get confused. Could someone explain to me how I can do it?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Eigen is mostly header-only library. All that you need is to add Eigen path to (MSVC2010):

**Project Properties** -> **C/C++** -> **General** -> **Additional Include Directories**

Let's say you have header **Core** in folder **C:/folder1/folder2/Eigen/**, i.e.:

```
C:/folder1/folder2/Eigen/Core
```

So you should add path **C:/folder1/folder2** to **Additional Include Directories**.

Comment: im geting can not open source file Eigen/Core

Comment: @crystalclear, where is your "Core" **file**? And what do you have in **Additional Include Directories**?

Comment: its on my c drive and i added the path in the additional include directories where eigen is

Comment: @crystalclear, what **exactly** do you have in **Additional Include Directories**?

Comment: C:\PTools\eigen-eigen-5097c01bcdc4\Eigen\src\Core;%(AdditionalIncludeDirectories)

Comment: @crystalclear, Instead you should use: **C:\PTools\eigen-eigen-5097c01bcdc4\;%(AdditionalIncludeDirectories‌​)**

Answer (score 3):

From the [Eigen docs](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/GettingStarted.html):

> #### How to "install" Eigen?
>
> In order to use [Eigen](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/namespaceEigen.html), you just need to download and extract Eigen's source code (see [the wiki](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Main_Page#Download) for download instructions). In fact, the header files in the `Eigen` subdirectory are the only files required to compile programs using Eigen. The header files are the same for all platforms. It is not necessary to use CMake or install anything.
>
> ...
>
> #### Compiling and running your first program
>
> There is no library to link to. The only thing that you need to keep in mind when compiling the above program is that the compiler must be able to find the Eigen header files. The directory in which you placed Eigen's source code must be in the include path.

So you don't actually install anything.